# Problem with Baofeng BF-888 radios

Tags: baofeng, equipment-troubleshooting

I have 2 Baofeng bt-888 radios coming out of the box. The problem is that the radios still growl on all channels and the light stays green. Le Griche stops when we send a communication or when we receive one. I have already tried to clone the radios with another one that I have that works fine without success.

Original French:

Bonjour j'ai 2 radios Baofeng bt-888 qui sorte de la boite. Le problème est que les radios griche toujours sur tout les canaux et la lumière reste verte. Le Griche arrête lorsque nous envoyons un communication ou lorsque nous en recevons une. J'ai déjà essayer de cloné les radios avec un autre que j'ai qui fonctionne très bien sans succès.

Comment: [Posts have to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684). It's not our job to make your question readable to the audience here; you can use an automated translation tool yourself.

Comment: Le français est une belle langue, mais sachez que nous n'acceptons que les questions en anglais. Il y a des traducteurs automatiques, et c'est le travail de celui qui pose une question de rendre la question compréhensible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Give him a break, like we are supposed to do for first-time posters.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, and welcome to this site! I moved your translation to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *growl* and *le Griche*?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the squelch is "open," so that any weak signal is let in and heard. The squelch needs to be increased, using software, so that you can only hear signals that are strong enough.

I don't have this radio, so my answer might not be completely correct.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1yiaNhU38g) video (I know that it's English, but hopefully it has useful information), at around 1 minute and 55 seconds, the software used to program the radio is shown. What you're looking for is "Squelch Level" (see original English) near the top and center of the program window. I don't know exactly what to set this to, but you should try to set it low enough that you hear strong signals but not constant noise.

I hope this helps. I've tried to use words that the translator program will translate correctly.

---

Bonjour,

Il semble que le problème soit que le silencieux est «ouvert», de sorte que tout signal faible est laissé entrer et entendu. Le silencieux doit être augmenté, à l'aide d'un logiciel, de sorte que vous ne puissiez entendre que des signaux suffisamment puissants.

Je n'ai pas cette radio, donc ma réponse n'est peut-être pas tout à fait correcte.

[Dans cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1yiaNhU38g) (je sais que c'est en anglais, mais j'espère qu'elle contient des informations utiles), à environ 1 minute et 55 secondes, le logiciel utilisé pour programmer la radio est montré. Ce que vous recherchez est "Squelch Level" (en anglais) près du haut et au centre de la fenêtre du programme. Je ne sais pas exactement sur quoi régler cela, mais vous devriez essayer de le régler suffisamment bas pour entendre des signaux forts mais pas un bruit constant.

J'espère que ça aide. J'ai essayé d'utiliser des mots que le programme de traduction traduira correctement.